# How to add form field of 2nd level child entity in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to figure out how to create a form field of 2nd child entity in symfony (2.6).
I have EntityA related to EntityB with foreign key fk_ab and EntityB related to EntityC with foreign key fk_bc
How can I add a form field from EntityC to EntityA?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need a collection field type in your parent form. It's type should be a custom form type. The custom form type should have a collection field as well (of another type).

It would go something like this:

```
->add('whatever')
->add('entityB', 'collection', array(
'type' => new EntityBType()
```

And for the child form (EntityBType):

```
->add('entityC', 'entity')
```

Basically you would have the EntityB form embedded into EntityA form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that's what I'm looking for. There's just one last thing, how can I display it in twig. When I do {{ form.entityB.entityC }} I get the following error method "entityc" doesn't exist in Entity/EntityA

Comment: If entityB is a collection type, you simply display it with {{form_row(entityB)}}. For it to work however you would have to set the entities relations before passing A to form: A->setChild(B), otherwise an empty collection will display.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I want to display entityC. I have set relations between entityA->entityB and entityB->entityC

Comment: Basically you use the collection type, because the entity type is rendered as a single field (usually select). This way you would get to choose the EntityB, but not EntityC. 
Thanks to collection type, you can instead render whole subform of EntityB (EntityBType). In this form you can add whichever fields you wish. If by displaying EntityC you mean EntityC's form (so you can edit the attributes or whatever), you simply embed another collection with a custom form type - EntityCType. That way in the A form you will have B form embedded, and in B - the C form.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is clear (collections are one of the more advanced form features), but it should steer you in the right direction. Feel free to ask of course.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's clear. Maybe I'm just doing things the wrong way. What I want to do is create a form for a search engine. I have three entities "car", "user" and "city". A car belongs to a user and a user lives in a city. I want to search cars by cities. The field City is a select.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I just added a field in the formbuilder with type "entity", class pointing to my entity, a query_builder and mapped to false. Everything is working fine now.